# how to sort by alphabetical order in firestore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Is possible to sort the database list by alphabetical order? I tried the sortby() function, but it didn't work properly

```
var snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Locations').where(
            "category", "==", type).orderBy('name','desc').get();
```

for example in the database: 1- name:chicken 2- name:pig 3- name:duck

after I sort by name, the order should be chicken, duck, pig

Here is how the database look, and the result after I ran my code.
[image: database]

[image: result]

As you can see, the result didn't sort by alphabe

Here is my indexes in firebase looks like
[image: Indexes]

Comment: Can you try `snapshot.docs.forEach(d => console.log(d.data()))` instead of whole array?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Hi, sorry, I'm confused a little bit. do I put this line of code under my code? if i put it under, the result is same as I posted above

Answer (score 0):

The query and the results are **right** .... The alphabetical order here will be according to encoding order(e.g ASCII, Unicode) where the capital letters are smaller that the small letters(the numbers comes first(smallest) then capital letters then the small ones: [0-9][A-Z][a-z])

The document in your image has(from bottom to top):

```
    Little - Maymar - Panda - Seafood - chicken - jade
```

Taking the first letter of each one and keep in mind the ASCII order, then its right:  `L->M->P->S->c->j`
And since you used 'desc' they'll come in the other way

One way to solve your problem is to make them all start with capital letter (or make them all starts with small letter as you like)

Comment: Hi Remoo, I tried change desc to asce, still doesn't work somehow.

Comment: I just updated my question with the Indexes picture in firesbase

Comment: In which order you want them to come ? use the one in the image '  Little - Maymar - Panda - Seafood - chicken - jade' in which order you want them?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use firestore's sortBy(), you can use javascript to sort the result of firestore response :

```
snapshot.docs.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.data().name.localCompare(b.data().name);
})
```